# How do kings secure their treasury?

Tags: monarchy, money

What part of a King's administrative structure ensures that the Treasury functions as expected, without employees taking advantage of their position (like manipulating accounts and stealing treasure, which in turn leads to the kingdom's collapse)? What stops people from stealing from the treasury, if the king is not going to be there to check all the activities all the time?

I've asked this question in the hope that, the answer to how the King controls his treasury may shed light on how he ensures stability.

Comment: Welcome to HistorySE, @Sreram! What has your research shown you so far?
Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You might find
it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help]. You may improve your
question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask].
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @MarkC.Wallace! I have been trying to find an answer on google, but I have found none after searching for a long time. My question is not about specific events or historical facts, but an inference from past monarch administrative structures. I couldn't find any sources on the internet that explains the mechanism that leads to the stability of kingdoms, or how kings in the past managed to make all their subjects listen to them. I'll edit my question to make this more clear.

Comment: Why should a kingdom be different from any other enterprise?  Those who embezzle from the enterprise get punished if they're caught, whether it's the "Off with his head!" of the absolute monarch, or arrest & trial in a western democracy, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rita_Crundwell  The fear of punishment (along with basic honesty and/or loyalty) tends to deter most would-be thieves.

Comment: It was common to assume that royal officials embezzled a lot of money. When King James VI & I visited his lord treasurer's vast Audley End mansion he said it was too big for a king, but doubtless just right for a lord treasurer, and later had him imprisoned for embezzlement.  Louis XIV's finance minister  Nicholas Fouquet had a similar downfall with his estate at Vaux-le-Vicomte.  James Brydges became so rich as paymaster during the War of the Spanish Succession he was made Duke of Chandos, and it was assumed he embezzled his wealth.

Comment: Hi! I've edited the question, in the hope that it fits the community (Now the question asks for just one thing: about how a king secures the treasury) Please tell me if there is any other change I must do, to ensure that this question fits the  community guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some related situations:

The [tower of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_London) or other similar fortresses and castles were used to store money. The [crown jewels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_Jewels_of_the_United_Kingdom) are still stored there.

Obviously, ["Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quis_custodiet_ipsos_custodes%3F) is an old problem, but they had, e.g., locks with could only be opened with 2 or more different keys. One example, during the famous indulgence controversy around Martin Luther time, the money chests always had 2 keys held by different persons, to avoid abuses.

The Templars transported money for the king (e.g., moving a chest full of gold coins from Paris to somewhere in France to pay soldiers during a war). The Templars charged a fee for this service, as they always needed income to finance their own army in the Holy Land. Presumably, the King trusted a knight's oath more than his own soldiers.

Another common situation is not to have any large treasury to be guarded. Portugal was in debt for long periods, thus any income would be quickly expended and there were no really large reserves, only current income/payments flows - i.e., bankers were the reserve and the real big money was in the banks.

For example, after 30y of deadlocked war against the Dutch in Brazil, the king made a conscious decision of borrowing money all around Europe - knowing that it would take decades to pay back -  to break the deadlock by financing the army that kicked the Dutch from Brazil in 1650. Do not expect a large royal treasure in Portugal for the next decades - the bankers had everything - a thief would  rather dream of robbing the [Fuggers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugger) than the king.

Comment: Thanks! "How do you guard the guards who guard the treasury" was exactly my question! From the outside, the king's administrative structure seems quite stable, but thinking about it even little further leads to a lot of similar loopholes and paradoxes. After all the "King" is just one man. But it is everyone else who do all the work for him. Stability in such a situation just feels impossible.

Comment: except by the tech (such as 2-key locks), the paradoxes are the same today, as human nature is the same.

Comment: Yes that's true. The paradoxes exists, but I think it has taken a different form today. Because today, "money" is just a number in a database record. Fractional reserve actually artificially create more money instantly, at any given time. Today, money is just a concept, not something we can hold on to. So basically, the guards will be the ones guarding a server. Even if they break open the server, it will be impossible for them to steal the money or at-least make sense of all the encrypted information! Just thinking about it makes me wonder how far humanity has come.

Comment: @Sreram ok, the next time I go to my bank office I will tell them to open the vault and let me in, as "money is just a number in a database record" and "money is just a concept" and "it will be impossible [...] to steal the money". I will tell you how well it works...

Comment: Business who sell share create money (or something similar to money), in the form of shares. And they give their "money" (their shares) value by making the business succeed. Today, "the guards who guard the treasury" are directly the ones who made the rules, and now the part of "guarding the guard" no longer takes the form where the lowest level employees are involved in this. It is all the highest level we must worry about.

Comment: @SJuan76 Of course they hold gold. The US initially had a policy that the amount of paper money in circulation was strictly in constant proportion to the amount of gold in their vaults. But today, this rule has changed, and dollars no longer represent a fixed value of gold. It has now become a floating value, and thus allowing inflation. 

Even if there are vaults that store money (paper money), the amount of money in such vaults will be just a fraction of the amount of money the bank deals with everyday or its net value.

Comment: @Sreram: But if you go to a bank that has $X in deposits, and somehow - say you're a really good hypnotist - persuade them to let you into their vault, you are going to find only a tiny fraction of that $X in actual cash - only enough to supply the daily needs of customers.  Keeping money around idle costs money, for guards & expensive vaults.  (Even for kings: a lot comes in as taxes, but it goes right back out to pay soldiers, tax collectors, and other flunkies.)

Comment: @jamesqf Exactly my point: the treasury will contain only a fraction of the money. That's why I spoke about inflation and fractional reserve. And yes, now that I think about it, the money in the King's treasury will not belong to him alone. It will eventually be distributed to everyone who works under him. Thus, a theft will result in an insecurity for the employee's livelihood as well.

Comment: @jamesqf the Fuggers also did not kept all their $ stored as gold coins in chests - they also lent money to clients or governments.